# Spree, Ruby on Rails - Add to cart multiple variants of the same product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I want customers to be allowed to add multiple variants of the same product on the same page. Now i have a list of variants with a radio button, how to make them **checkboxes**?
Of course, changing "radio_button_tag" to "check_box_tag" not helping

```
<% @product.variants_and_option_values(current_currency).each_with_index do |variant, index| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag "products[#{@product.id}]", variant.id, index == 0, 'data-price' => variant.price_in(current_currency).display_price %>
  <%= variant_options variant %>
<% end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets create an example, where the product ID is 1, and you're trying to add variants with id's of 11, and 12.

When you change radio_button_tag to check_box_tag the following parameters will be posted:

```
products[1]:11
products[1]:12
quantity:1
```

When this gets interpreted by Rack, it will see that you have 2 variables with the same name, meaning it will choose the last one specified.  Your params hash will look something like this:

```
{
  "products"=>{"1"=>"12"},
  "quantity"=>"1"
}
```

The simplest modification that you could make to this would be to change your checkbox tag to be:

```
<%= check_box_tag "products[#{@product.id}][]", variant.id, index == 0, 'data-price' => variant.price_in(current_currency).display_price %>
```

This will make your hash look like:

The simplest modification that you could make to this would be to change your checkbox tag to be:

```
{
  "products"=>{"1"=>["11", "12"]},
  "quantity"=>"1"
}
```

You'll then need to modify this code in the [Spree::OrderPopulator](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.0.4/core/app/models/spree/order_populator.rb#L21) to deal with the array passed in (rather than an integer).  Something like:

```
  from_hash[:products].each do |product_id,variant_ids|
    variant_ids.each do |variant_id|
      attempt_cart_add(variant_id, from_hash[:quantity])
    end
  end if from_hash[:products]
```

And you should be good to go.